# Differences of $V_1 \cup V_2$ and $V_1 +V_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V_1,V_2$ are subspaces of vector space
 $V$ . Differences of $V_1 \cup  V_2$ and $V_1 +V_2$ ?

Comment: @Najib: Poor selection, NOT a duplicate of your linked post. Please read questions before jumping the gun. (Don't be so quick to close questions you haven't bothered to read, or using a linked post you think addresses the question, but of which you haven't actually read **and compared.**) **This post** is asking for the difference between the union of two subspaces and their sum. Nowhere do I see any question related to whether $V_1\cup V_2$ is a subspace.

Comment: @amWhy By definition, $V_1 + V_2$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $V_1 \cup V_2$. So if $V_1 \cup V_2$ is not a subspace... I did read the post, thank you very much... I do assume the OP knows the most basic definitions though. Maybe that's asking too much from your point of view?

Answer (score 7):

Let $V = \Bbb R^2,V_1 = \{(x,0)\mid x \in \Bbb R\}$ and $V_2 = \{(0,y)\mid y \in \Bbb R\}$. Then $$V_1 + V_2 = \big\{(x,y)=(x,0)+(0,y)\in \Bbb R^2 \mid (x,0) \in V_1 \text{ and }(0,y)\in V_2\big\}=\Bbb R^2$$ but $$V_1 \cup V_2 =\{(a,b)\in \Bbb R^2\mid a=0 \text{ or } b = 0\} \neq \Bbb R^2$$

Answer (score 4):

The first is in general not a subspace and is the set of vectors that are in $V_1$ or in $V_2$. The second is the set of sums $v_1 + v_2$ where $v_i \ in V_i$ and is a subspace. It is by the way generated as vector space by the first one.